# excel output giving me result of column as comma seperated

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am Using Lucee and one of my Columns is proving me a value as comma separated value from database. I want it to be formatted to show it bit changed

Value in query:

```
a,b,c
```

Should display like in excel in the same row as:

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: Use either a database or coldfusion function to replace the commas with line breaks.

Comment: i am using sql server, what should i be using for line breaks, i tried with \n\r but that does not work

Comment: Use the char() function, as per this reference.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CHAR` Option in SQL Server, That will Solve Your Problem.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful to others if it explained *how* `char()` could be applied to produce the expected result.